# Indoor navigation using esp32 as BLE beacons and Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, navigation, esp32, rssi

I have to create an indoor navigation system to navigate visually impaired people in an art exhibition.
Since the exhibition area is quite large and has more rooms and corridors, I wanted to use multiple ESP32 as BLE beacons and an Android device with a Unity application to detect its relative position through RSSI and navigate users with vibrations.

It's my first time working on such project and I was wondering if anyone has any suggestion about how to approach this project, or if this is even feasible (with this setup).

Any opinion is highly appreciated!